# how to process linux find command didn't has result

Tags: bash, find, xargs, rm

> find . -name "*.pyc" -print0| xargs -0 rm

i use this command delete python compiled file but if current directory didn't have any *.pyc
file this cmd will not work
print out the error with rm command need operator args

how to handle this work if current directory didn't have *.pyc file this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Using find `-exec`:

```
find -name '*.pyc' -exec rm {} \;
```

or the discard output technique:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -print0| xargs -0 -I{} rm {} &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume GNU find, then you can use `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete`.

Alternatively, `find . -name '*.pyc' -exec rm -rf {} '+'`.